# JComboBox with static options

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am looking for a Java Swing Combo Box that will enable me to have **static** options on the selectable list. My immediate goal is: I need a combo box with a "add new" option at the bottom, but the add new option will always be visible (i.e., it will be excluded from the combo box's scroll pane).

I have used a snip from Asana project management to illustrate:

[image]

This is an auto-complete textbox/combobox of items. *`Item 2`*, *`Item 1`*, and *`Item 3`* were all previously used, but if you need another tag, you select *`NEW TAG`* which is always visible.

Does anyone know of any libraries out there that would implement this functionality? If not, I am considering creating it myself, although my knowledge of Swing is not deep enough for this to be an obvious problem to solve.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to have a button next to the combobox that opens a dialog, otherwise you have to start extending combobox and overriding the draw methods, it gets complicated quickly.

Comment: or don't use a jcombobox, use a jtextcomponent with a jwindow below and then add a panel to the jwindow

Comment: Well, I am at least encouraged, because both of you have touched on my current solution to this problem. :) Currently, I display a borderless window that has an "add new" button. But, it's a lot of code to show/hide the button at the appropriate time, and it's even more complicated when it comes to focusing the button, pressing the button, etc. I've done it for one combobox, I was hoping for a more elegant solution for the rest. An always-visible combo box is not an option because of screen real-estate issues.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have code here, but when i make my autocomplete component i guide a little with 
this [JSuggestField](https://github.com/Yoyo117/ModularWotClanInfo/blob/master/src/modularwotclaninfo/JSuggestField.java). I make it a little bigger with more features but may it helps you. 
Instead of extending you can decorate the textfield autocompletion with composition.

You have a `JTextField` , a JWindow below the JTextField , and in the jwindow you can put your own layout and putting a jpanel below.

Comment: I've actually already implemented the `JWindow` solution (with a `JButton` inside the `JWindow`), but it's kludgy and not very reusable in my case. Perhaps I should just refine that solution and fit it for re-usability. Honestly, the auto complete solutions I've encountered are also less-than-desirable (I'm looking at you, `SwingX`) so maybe this would be a fruitful project.

Comment: It's the first time I've seen such a GUI element, and think its utility (in general) is too limited or specialized to have much interest from the SwingX folks.  Of course, I am not one of them and should not speak on their behalf, but that is my best guess.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, yes it is specialized but the more projects I work on, the more I'm beginning to see a shift in the end-user's control of metadata in applications. My current app is built heavily on user-controlled metadata (i.e., what appears in the comboboxes) and my first approach was to provide separate windows for the CRUD of these objects, but my clients want more: the ability to use what's entered or create new metadata on the fly. This is becoming the norm in my sphere of development, Asana PM being an excellent example of the potential for such apps.

Comment: *"my clients want more"*  Yes, agreed.  That is a very common attribute of users.  So I get your point now.  Hope it goes well for you. :)  And hey, if you come up with a great implementation 1) Answer your own question. 2) Submit it to SwingX! One great (very persuasive) part of an RFE is working source code.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I found another practical application for this (to show that it's not too specific): gmail. :) http://i.imgur.com/FVocgCW.png